# NameError when trying to read user input in Python

Tags: python, input, nameerror

Hy! I'm creating a software that computes probability.
My problem is that when I want to ask what kind of items are we talking about and I write it, i get syntax error.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import division
from scipy.stats import hypergeom
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from operator import itemgetter
from random import randint
import scipy.special
import math
import random
from scipy.stats import binom

object = str(input("What kind of items are we talking about?"))
population = int(input("How many " + object + "do we have?"))
```

the error:

```
    What kind of items are we talking about?car
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/suhajdakrisztian/PycharmProjects/firsttrial/input.nemtudomanevet.py", line 12, in <module>
    object = str(input("What kind of items are we talking about?"))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'car' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: As Shiva's answer suggests, input is a string by default, so you don't need to call str() on the first input.

Comment: BTW, don't use `object` as a variable name because that shadows the built-in `object` type.